# regex, character separated by coma and -

Tags: java, regex

I want check the format of a String. The formats possible are :

```
-15
-15,19
-15-19
-4C
-4C-19
-4C,19
-4C,5T
-4C-5T
```

and also combinations of all :

```
-4"-5T,15,8P,10-13
```

So for example, `"4C"_"5T"` is not valid because there is `_`

Curently I have this but it works juste when there are only numbers :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d\\,(?=\\d))|(\\d\\-(?=\\d))|\\d)+");
```

It doesn't works if I replace 'd' by 'w'...

How can I do ?

(I work on Java)

Comment: What are your other requirements? From what I can see here, it looks like you have 2 characters text with quotes and they are preceded by either a dash or comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^-\"\\d+\\w?\"(?:-\"\\d+\\w?\")?(?:,\"\\d+\\w?\"(?:-\"\\d+\\w?\")?)*$");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eQ2gW3/1)

Comment: I'm sorry but There are not " .. I will edit my post

Comment: Ok I edited your solution and it's works ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see, I assume that these are the requirements.

- Either a `-` or a `,`; then
- 2 alphanumeric characters surrounded by double quotes

Here is the pattern that you can use.

```
Pattern.compile("([-,]\"\\w{2}\")+")
```